# SQL Server Group BY weekly clause blank if no data

Tags: sql, sql-server

No. 1 Query group by weekly

```
SELECT
    DATEADD(week, DATEDIFF(week, 0, DailyDate), 0) AS WeekStart, 
    SUM(Soil) AS TotalSoil, 
    SUM(Rock) AS TotalRock, 
    SUM(Concrete) AS TotalConcrete, 
    SUM(Steel) AS TotalSteel, 
    SUM(MovementPiles) AS TotalMovementPiles, 
    SUM(Total) AS OverallTotal
FROM 
    BplPjtRevenueStreams
WHERE 
    DailyDate > '2016-11-28 00:00:00.000' 
    AND DailyDate < '2016-12-05 00:00:00.000' 
    AND Project_Id = 5
GROUP BY 
    DATEADD(week, DATEDIFF(week, 0, DailyDate), 0)
```

[image: Result for first query]

No. 2 query which have empty data in the table since table has no project_Id = 6 yet

```
SELECT
    DATEADD(week, DATEDIFF(week, 0, DailyDate), 0) AS WeekStart, 
    SUM(Soil) AS TotalSoil, 
    SUM(Rock) AS TotalRock, 
    SUM(Concrete) AS TotalConcrete, 
    SUM(Steel) AS TotalSteel, 
    SUM(MovementPiles) AS TotalMovementPiles, 
    SUM(Total) AS OverallTotal
FROM
    BplPjtRevenueStreams
WHERE 
    DailyDate > '2016-11-28 00:00:00.000' 
    AND DailyDate < '2016-12-05 00:00:00.000' 
    AND Project_Id = 6
GROUP BY 
    DATEADD(week, DATEDIFF(week, 0, DailyDate), 0)
```

[image: Image for second query]

May I know if I want to do something like this for the No. 2 query?

```
  Week Start              TotalSoil  TotalRock TotalConcrete TotalSteel TotalMovementPiles OverallTotal
1 2016-11-28 00:00:00.000  NULL       NULL       NULL         NULL          NULL              NULL
1 2016-12-05 00:00:00.000  NULL       NULL       NULL         NULL          NULL              NULL
```

Is it possible to do like this if it's empty result in the table?

Comment: Yes, make a tally table for the weeks `left join` with your query, then you can get the rows with empty data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE 
    @Project_Id int = 6, 
    @RangeFrom datetime = '2016-11-28 00:00:00.000', 
    @RangeTo datetime = '2016-12-05 00:00:00.000' 

;WITH Numbers AS 
(
    SELECT * FROM (VALUES(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10)) t(Value)
), Weeks AS 
(
    -- All weeks start from year 2000, Monday
    SELECT DATEADD(WEEK, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)), '1999-12-27') AS DateValue 
    FROM Numbers a CROSS JOIN Numbers b CROSS JOIN Numbers c CROSS JOIN Numbers d
), Data AS 
(
    -- This is your query
    SELECT
        DATEADD(week, DATEDIFF(week, 0, DailyDate), 0) AS WeekStart, 
        SUM(Soil) AS TotalSoil, 
        SUM(Rock) AS TotalRock, 
        SUM(Concrete) AS TotalConcrete, 
        SUM(Steel) AS TotalSteel, 
        SUM(MovementPiles) AS TotalMovementPiles, 
        SUM(Total) AS OverallTotal
    FROM
        BplPjtRevenueStreams
    WHERE 
        DailyDate > @RangeFrom
        AND DailyDate < @RangeTo
        AND Project_Id = @Project_Id
    GROUP BY 
        DATEADD(week, DATEDIFF(week, 0, DailyDate), 0)
)
SELECT 
    CAST(w.DateValue AS datetime) AS WeekStart, 
    d.TotalSoil,
    d.TotalRock,
    d.TotalConcrete,
    d.TotalSteel,
    d.TotalMovementPiles,
    d.OverallTotal
FROM Weeks w LEFT OUTER JOIN Data d ON w.DateValue = CAST(d.WeekStart AS date)
WHERE 
    w.DateValue BETWEEN CAST(@RangeFrom AS date) AND CAST(@RangeTo AS date)
```

Comment: omg, it works like a charm, but I don't understand this few lines of your query why I need to do that
";WITH Numbers AS 
(
    SELECT * FROM (VALUES(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10)) t(Value)
), Weeks AS 
(
    SELECT DATEADD(WEEK, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)), '1999-12-27') AS DateValue 
    FROM Numbers a CROSS JOIN Numbers b CROSS JOIN Numbers c CROSS JOIN Numbers d
)"

Comment: @jefferyleo It just build a simple table for the weeks

Comment: is it possible to create a #temp table for the weeks to left join also?